# Cartan decomposition diffeomorphism at the level of (compact) groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand the Cartan decomposition in the case of a compact group $G$ with subgroup $K$, such that their respective Lie algebras $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{k})$ correspond to a Cartan pair for an involution $\theta$.

In this setting, we have a decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the -1 eigenspace of the involution $\theta$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. When I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition, it seems that $G$ must be diffeomorphic to $K\times \mathfrak{p}$, and this diffeomorphism is there called "Global Cartan Decomposition". 
[**Edit**: 
More precisely, I am refering to the statement :

"The mapping $K×\mathfrak{p}→G$ given by $(k,X)↦k⋅exp(X)$ is a diffeomorphism" in the section "Cartan decomposition on the Lie group level".
]

What I don't understand is  that $K\times \mathfrak{p}$ is not compact (right?), but I want to consider $G$ as a compact group. Is there a mistake in the wikipedia page? Or is it only true for non-compact groups ? If so, what is then known about the Cartan decomposition at the level of groups for compact groups ?

Comment: The group is compact but its Lie algebra is not.

Comment: yes, and precisely $\mathfrak{p}$ is not compact, while $G$ is compact, so there is problem in the statement "$G$ is diffeomorphic with $K\times \mathfrak{p}$" (a missing hypothesis), right ?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which sentence at the Wikipedia page or elsewhere you disbelieve? The "simple" Cartan decomposition is always a decomposition of a Lie algebra which is always noncompact. There is never any contradiction with the group's  being compact. In particular, the Lie algebra contains the Cartan subalgebra and the corrsponding subrgoup of the group is the maximal torus which is nothing else than the Cartan Lie subalgebra with some periodicity imposed on the coordinates. When made periodic, the coordinates label a compact space.

Comment: I am refering to the statement "The mapping $K\times \mathfrak {p}\rightarrow G$ given by ${\displaystyle (k,X)\mapsto k\cdot \mathrm {exp} (X)}$ is a diffeomorphism," in the section "Cartan decomposition on the Lie group level".

Comment: I am aware of the decomposition at the level of Lie algebras, which of course are non-compact. I am talking about the level of groups.

Comment: Dear Jon-S, there is nothing wrong about the statement that it is a diffeomorphism, which means a smooth map. The map isn't a one-to-one map, and no one claims that it should be one. General maps can map a noncompact manifold to a compact one. In the simplest U(1) case, exp(iz) is a periodic function with periodicity 2*pi, so it converts the noncompact "z" in "R" to a compact unit circle. This is the basic toy model whose "power" describes the situation in the Cartan subgroups-subalgebras of all Lie groups and algebras.

Comment: I've never seen anyone use the "diffeomorphism" word to just mean "smooth". The standard terminology for "diffeomorphism" is that it is smooth, bijective, and such that the inverse is smooth.

Comment: OK, great, if you study the variables carefully, the K part on both sides is compact and the other part is added as noncompact coordinates,  and this map is one-to-one, after all. If you parameterize the group manifold G, you may do so in a way that all the compact periodic coordinates are in the K part and all the remaining coordinates are aperiodic and equivalent to $R^+$. There's still no mistake in the sentence.

Comment: What I am saying is this : if this sentence is true for $G$ compact, then we have a contradiction. Because $\mathfrak{p}$ is non-compact, therefore, $K\times \mathfrak{p}$ is non-compact, therefore $G$ (through the diffeomorphism) is non-compact. I am then just suggesting that maybe we need to suppose $G$ non-compact for the sentence to be true.

Comment: The decomposition is surely meant to be used for compact groups, too. It's just some places of the group manifold where the inverse map is allowed to be discontinuous. One effectively cuts the compact group manifold G at those places and the cut G looks noncompact.

Comment: If you look in Knapp's "Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction," although he claims that the statement is always true (regardless of compactness), you are correct that the map is a diffeomorphism only in the non-compact case. I believe his proof shows that even in the compact case the map is a smooth bijection (page 362-368).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is simply false. Cartan's theorem says says if $G$ is semi-simple, and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup, then $(G,K)$ is a symmetric pair, and if $\cal p$ is the orthogonal in $\cal G$ of the Lie algebra of $ K$ $\exp :{\cal P}\to G/K$ is a diffeomrophism. This is a special case of the Cartan-Hadamard theorem which says that for a complete simply connected manifold of non positive curvature the exponential map is a diffeomorphism.